# JS exception in a JSP running on WebSphere 6.1

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, jsp, websphere

I have popup searcher in my application which lists the available record as hyperlink. Onclick of these links we are populating a textbox with the value.

The popup is opened using **window.open** method. The hyperlinks in the searcher looks like this:

When I invoke the searcher with IE's debugging enabled I am getting an error at the line where hyper link is present. When I change the hyper link to  no error is displayed.

We are using **WebSphere 6.1** on **IBM AIX** and browser **IE7**.

When the same application is running in WebSphere installed on a **windows** system, we are **not receiving** any error even in the former case.

Can this be because of some server level settings? If yes what is that setting?

Note: the searcher is written in a **JSP**.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the syntax of the hyperlink calling the JavaScript method. Instead of having href="javascript:method()" we had written href"method()".

Comment: You're supposed to use `onclick` for that.

Answer (score 0):

What error do you get? What do the hyperlinks look like in two cases, good case and the bad case?

Seems very likely that the specifics of the generated hyperlinks differ due to some environmental factor. So first think to find out is if indeed that's true. Once you know what's different it should be possible to figure why.